# How can I create a loop where i only take words that start with capital letters

Tags: r, loops, analytics, capitalization

I have an excel sheet with a lot of rows and i want: to split the rows in a specific column by commas (this column describes ancestry and it has numbers and commas), then create a function where i only take words that start with capital letters. Then abstract these words and put them in a loop, so I can create a list of words that go together in a  row that start with capital letters. After that i want to create a list where i can see the frequencies of each of these words.

I used the function str_extract_all(data$`INITIAL SAMPLE DESCRIPTION`, "\b[A-Z]\w*") |> unique()
Where `INITIAL SAMPLE DESCRIPTION` is the name of the column of my interest.

Comment: Please show us a reproducible sample of data and the expected output. String parsing is very dependent on the _exact_ details of the input and expected output.

Comment: These are examples of the rows that are in this specific column: "191 European ancestry individuals
617 European ancestry cases, 4,583 European ancestry controls
1,113 European, African, Oceania, Hispanic and other ancestry individuals from 418 families
322 Plains American Indian ancestry individuals" ...   And I want a list that would contain words like "European, African, Plain American Indian..."

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Extract words with an initial capital letter followed by any alphabetic character zero or more times.
To table the result above, well, `unlist` and `table` it.

```r
x <- 'I have an excel sheet with a lot of rows and i want: to split the rows in a specific column by commas (this column describes ancestry and it has numbers and commas), then create a function where i only take words that start with capital letters. Then abstract these words and put them in a loop, so I can create a list of words that go together in a row that start with capital letters. After that i want to create a list where i can see the frequencies of each of these words.
I used the function str_extract_all(data$INITIAL SAMPLE DESCRIPTION, "\\b[A-Z]\\w*") |> unique() Where INITIAL SAMPLE DESCRIPTION is the name of the column of my interest.
'
cap <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z][[:alpha:]]*")
cap
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "I"           "Then"        "I"           "After"       "I"          
#>  [6] "INITIAL"     "SAMPLE"      "DESCRIPTION" "A"           "Z"          
#> [11] "Where"       "INITIAL"     "SAMPLE"      "DESCRIPTION"

cap |> unlist() |> table()
#> 
#>           A       After DESCRIPTION           I     INITIAL      SAMPLE 
#>           1           1           2           3           2           2 
#>        Then       Where           Z 
#>           1           1           1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Apply the code above to each column element.
Written as a function:

```
extract_cap_words <- function(x) {
  stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z][[:alpha:]]*")
}

lapply(data$`INITIAL SAMPLE DESCRIPTION`, extract_cap_words)
```

Comment: thanks it works :). But some of the entries in the rows contain two words that start with a capital letter like "Han Chinese" and i want a list where these words are not separated

Comment: @OliwiaRoszak Can you [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77704163/edit) with sample data and corresponding output?